# DelayQueue multiple take calls

Tags: java, collections, queue

I am going to be using DelayQueue from the Collections interface in a program that simulates a parking lot.  I was wondering if there are multiple take method calls to a queue while no elements have expired, does the last take call return the element that comes out first, or does it return the element that comes out after the previously called take?

Comment: `take` will wait for the first expired element and then return it, you can't have multiple `take` calls waiting in the same thread. If you have several take calls one after another then they will return the elements in the order of expiration,

Comment: Okay, and is it the first or last take call that receives the next element out?

Comment: The first call will return the element which expired first. the next one the second, and so on.

Comment: Also does take open a new thread to wait for the next expired element?  Or does it pause the main thread?

Comment: It pauses the thread it was called from.

Comment: And since IIRC DelayQueue is not fair, there is no guarantee as to which thread will be served first should you use multiple threads.

Comment: Okay thank you, I am using only one thread in this, but I'll have to see if it works as intended

Comment: sure, don't forget to post an update so that I could refine the answer or so that the question could be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `DelayQueue.take`'s javadoc:

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary
>   until an element with an expired delay is available on this queue.

That is something like that:

```
DelayQueue<DelayedSomething> q = new DelayQueue<>();

q.offer(somethingExpiringIn60s);
q.offer(somethingExpiringIn5s);
q.offer(somethingExpiringIn5min);

DelayedSomething shouldBeSomethingExpiringIn5s = q.take(); //[1]
DelayedSomething shouldBeSomethingExpiringIn60s = q.take(); //[2]
DelayedSomething shouldBeSomethingExpiringIn5min = q.take(); //[3]
```

Will work like that - the `[1]` call will block the current thread for 5s, then return the second inserted element. The `[2]` will block the current thread for 55s, then returning the first inserted element. The `[3]` `take` call will block for 4 minutes, eventually returning the last inserted element.

If you want to use `DelayQueue` in a multithreaded environment please note that it DOES NOT guarantee fairness (it would be fair if the threads calling `take` would be served in the same order as they called `take`) - it's implementation-dependent, and in OpenJDK 7 and 8 it does not use fair locks for implementation - so order in which the threads would be served is arbitrary.